# Mongoose query with boolean

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to perform a query with mongoose, but can't seem to get the right sintax. This is currently what I have:

```
db.find({}, 'Link -_id', function (error, existingData) {
  console.log(existingData);
}
```

Now, this returns from the collection all the Links, which are what I need. But I need to add a condition to the query where I only get the links that have a true boolean. For example, the boolean is "useful". So my question basically is how do I set the condition on that query to obtain the Links that have a `"Useful: true"` condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following changes in your code .

If in your model , the value of key `Useful` is stored in string i.e., `Userful : "true"` , then apply the below code .

```
=> db.find({Useful : "true"}, 'Link -_id', function (error, existingData) { console.log(existingData);
```

If in your model , the value of key `Useful` is stored as boolean i.e., `Userful : true` , then apply the below code .

```
=> db.find({Useful : true}, 'Link -_id', function (error, existingData) { console.log(existingData);
```